# Random graph on the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ as the graph of which the vertices are $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the edges are the couples $\{v_1,v_2\}$ in which $|v_1-v_2| = 1$ in the euclidean metric.

now remove each edge with probability $p$ independently.

Consider the event

$A_p = \{$ in the graph we created there is an infinite connectted component $\}$

Thia is of course a tail event and thus from Kolmogorov's zero–one law we have

$\mathbb{P}(A_p)\in \{0,1\}$

Now, $f(p)= \mathbb{P}(A_p)$ is monotonic and we have $f(0)=1 , f(1)=0$ so we have a critical point $c$ of which $f$ jumps from $1$ to $0$

This example was brought to us in class and I wonder, can $c$ be evaluated? Even if ther is a way to numericlly evaluate it I think that could be interesting so if anyone knows or has an idea on how to compute it I would love to hear!

Also is there a way to know if $f(c)$ is $1$ or $0$?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more reaserch, this procces is called Percolation and the answer is
$c = \frac{1}{2}$.

I will leave it open in case someone else will think of this and will not know what is Percolation.